# DevExpress WPF one to many reference and etc:)

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, nhibernate, devexpress

i'm stucked...
Here's my problem.
I've server and client side.

Server retrieved data from mssql database with Fluent nHibernate as strongly typed entities.
After all, i'm retrieving all of those entities through JSON protocol over network.
On the client side i've a data access layer, but... here's a problem...
My entity looks like this:

```
public class Foo
{
   public virtual long ID { get; set; }
   public virtual string Name { get; set; }
   public virtual IList<BlahBlah> BlahBlahs { get; set; }
}
```

Where BlahBlahs is a one to many reference.
Ok. I've got and filled entity... But how can i make DevExpress GridView (WPF) display it correctly?
I mean, that BlahBlahs as a table grid as well...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is nested only one level deep, you can use [Master-Detail](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#wpf/CustomDocument6288) approach. Otherwise you'll need to use [TreeListControl](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/clsDevExpressXpfGridTreeListControltopic).